# Use duplicates from that TreeSet and print the duplicates out

Tags: java, duplicates, treeset

How to use duplicates from that `TreeSet` and print the duplicates out?

I created a method that allows me to fill an array with no duplicates from a text file, now I need to get those duplicates to writhe them in another file.  How do I do that?

```
// method that gets that reads the file and puts it in to an array
public static void readFromfile() throws IOException {
    // Open the file.
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    // create a new array set Integer list
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    // add the numbers to the list
    while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        set.add(inputFile.nextInt());
    }
    // transform the Set list in to an array
    Integer[] numbersInteger = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);

    // loop that print out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersInteger.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbersInteger[i]);
    }

    // close the input stream
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow!

Comment: use the return value of `set.add(inputFile.nextInt());`

Answer (score 4):

You can collect duplicates while adding into `TreeSet` or any `Set`:

```
List<Integer> dups = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> noDups= new TreeSet<Integer>();
int i;
        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        {
            if(!noDups.add(i=inputFile.nextInt()))
                dups.add(i);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> duplicates = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        // add the numbers to the list
        while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
            Integer it = inputFile.nextInt();
            if (set.contains(it)) {
                duplicates.add(it); // adding duplicates which is already present in Set
            } else {
                set.add(it); // if not present in set add to Set
            }
        }

// loop ArrayList print duplicates values
```